# Unmarshaling JSON into a UUID type

Tags: json, go

I'm trying to use the json.Unmarshaler interface to unmarshal a UUID into a uuid.UUID field on a struct. I created a custom type called myUUID and everything works until I try to access methods that are normally on uuid.UUID. How can I handle this? I'm relatively new to Go, so maybe I just don't fully understand custom types just yet.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "code.google.com/p/go-uuid/uuid"
)

var jsonstring = `
{
    "uuid": "273b62ad-a99d-48be-8d80-ccc55ef688b4"
}
`

type myUUID uuid.UUID

type Data struct {
    uuid myUUID
}

func (u *myUUID) UnmarshalJson(b []byte) error {
    id := uuid.Parse(string(b[:]))
    if id == nil {
            return errors.New("Could not parse UUID")
    }
    *u = myUUID(id)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    d := new(Data)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstring), &d)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d.uuid.String())
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go's custom types [don't inherit methods](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language). I refactored the code using a custom struct and attaching an UnmarshalJSON.

```
import (
        "errors"
        "strings"

        "github.com/pborman/uuid"
)


type ServiceID struct {
    UUID uuid.UUID
}

type Meta struct {
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Version string `json:"version"`
    SID     *ServiceID `json:"UUID"`
}

func (self *ServiceID) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    s := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    self.UUID = uuid.Parse(s)
    if self.UUID == nil {
            return errors.New("Could not parse UUID")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: How can this work or even compile? in the type ServiceId UUID is not a pointer, so how can `if self.UUID == nil {` compile?

Comment: @emaborsa because `uuid.UUID` is actually `[]byte` and slices can be nil. See: https://github.com/pborman/uuid/blob/master/uuid.go#L32

Comment: Actually I get two compile errors. First `cannot assign 2 values to 1 variables` on `Parse`, second `cannot convert nil (untyped nil value) to uuid.UUID` on `self.UUID == nil`. First is simply fixable by adding the second return value, or even skip it like `self.UUID, _ = uuid.Parse(s)`. Second I have to define the UUID property as a pointer like `UUID *uuid.UUID`, but then the assignment of Parse complains.

Comment: @Emaborsa I'm guessing the UUID package you are using is `github.com/google/uuid`, which indeed does return 2 parameters from its `Parse` function and uses a buffered array (not nullable) for the UUID bytes. However, the original question refers to `code.google.com/p/go-uuid/uuid`, which is now `github.com/pborman/uuid` and does not return an `error` value from `Parse` and uses an unbuffered byte slice (nullable). I will update the answer to include the required imports to support the answer, which does compile.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to make sure your `myuuid` variable is visible/exported in the `Data struct`: as in "public".
Same for the type alias `MyUUID` (instead of `myUUID`)

```
type MyUUID uuid.UUID

type Data struct {
    Uuid MyUUID
}
```

From [JSON and Go](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go):

> The json package only accesses the exported fields of struct types (those that begin with an uppercase letter).

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258439/unmarshaling-json-into-a-uuid-type/25258482#comment39356051_25258482) by [Ainar G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1892060/ainar-g), the [style guide](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Initialisms) also recommends:

> Words in names that are initialisms or acronyms (e.g. "`URL`" or "`NATO`") have a consistent case.
>   For example, "`URL`" should appear as "`URL`" or "`url`" (as in "`urlPony`", or "`URLPony`"), never as "`Url`". Here's an example: `ServeHTTP` not `ServeHttp`.
>
> This rule also applies to "`ID`" when it is short for "identifier," so write "`appID`" instead of "`appId`".

In your case, that would mean:

```
type Data struct {
    UUID MyUUID
}
```

Comment: ``Uuid`` should also be ``UUID``. See [the style guide](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CodeReviewComments#Initialisms).

Comment: @Ainar-G true. I have included that commend in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: and if I want to make `uuid` a private attribute, it should be named `uUID`? Likewise `uRL`, `hTTPStatus`?

Comment: @warvariuc no: `uuid`, `httpStatus` (the case needs to be consistent), except in the OP's case, it needs to be public in order to be accessed by JSON.

Comment: I am not talking about JSON case, but generally about private/public attributes. This smells. I think making attributes private, by prefixing them with `_` (like in Python) would be a better choice of Go designers.

Comment: @warvariuc no, again, consistent case is enough: `uuid` or `httpStatus` are perfectly acceptable names for private variables. '`_`' is not.

Comment: I would gladly use `httpStatus` and `HttpStatus`, but this is against the guide.

Comment: @warvariuc, no only `HttpStatus` is against the guide. For a public name, it should be `HTTPStatus`.

Comment: So `HTTPStatus` for a public attribute and `httpStatus` for a private attribute? This is new to me.

Comment: @warvariuc there is nothing "new" here: start with lowercase for private variables, uppercase for public ones. Except that in the case of initialisms or acronyms, the lowercase/uppercase convention should not be limited to the first letter, but applied *consistently* for the all word. Hence `HTTPStatus` and `httpStatus`

Comment: @VonC I have exported the MyUUID type and UUID field and I'm still seeing the missing methods error: d.UUID.String undefined (type MyUUID has no field or method String)

Comment: @Ainar-G As shown in http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go, the data struct and the JSON string should have the same names for their fields. Did you modify your `jsonstring` as well?

Comment: @VonC Yes, I changed the jsonstring field to UUID and even tried using a tag in the struct: UUID MyUUID `json:"UUID"`

Comment: @Ainar-G can you try with jsonstring = `{"UUID":"273b62ad-a99d-48be-8d80-ccc55ef688b4"}` (no space between UUID and its value)

Comment: Looks like Go's custom types don't inherit methods from the "parent" type. I changed how I structures the code to work around this and made a custom UnmarshalJSON method to handle that.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to revise the above solutions to provide one that:

1. works with the Google UUID library
2. compiles
3. produces a JSON string with the canonical UUID forma `273b62ad-a99d-48be-8d80-ccc55ef688b4`

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

var jsonstring = `
{
    "uuid": "273b62ad-a99d-48be-8d80-ccc55ef688b4"
}
`

type myUUID uuid.UUID

type Data struct {
    Uuid myUUID  `json:"uuid"`
}

func (u *myUUID) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    id, err := uuid.Parse(string(b[:]))
    if err != nil {
            return err
    }
    *u = myUUID(id)
    return nil
}

func (u *myUUID) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", uuid.UUID(*u).String())), nil
}

func main() {
    d := new(Data)
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstring), &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Output: [39 59 98 173 169 157 72 190 141 128 204 197 94 246 136 180]
    fmt.Println(d.Uuid)
    s, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Output: {"uuid":"273b62ad-a99d-48be-8d80-ccc55ef688b4"}
    fmt.Println(string(s))
}
```